# Cann endermen spawn in a big area with the light level being dark?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I make a boxed in area big enough to support an enderman, could an enderman spawn because of the light level being so dark? I will try it today to see if there will be any endermen but if not I might try again.

Answer (score 1):

Hostile mobs spawn anywhere with light level 7 or less (and where they can fit physically), enclosure does not affect spawning.

See [the list of conditions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Spawn_conditions) on the wiki (and the rest of the article).